# Take span out of its span parent and give the parent a class

Tags: jquery

```
I have this html:

<span class="titreck">
L
<span class="descck">Column 1</span>
</span>
```

I need to give the titreck span another class, but also to take descck span out of its parent titreck span.

There are also other titreck spans on the page, I need to affect this one only.

I tried using unwrap which destroys the titreck span, but the L letter remains, which is a problem.

First I gave the the parent span a class with:

```
$('span.descck').parent().addClass('hideme');
```

Then used unwrap like so:

```
$('span.descck').unwrap();
```

But the L letter remains, I need just the content inside descck span to remain.

Comment: Please include the code which you tried that did not work.

Comment: Done. Can I somehow just remove the L now, or should I try something different? thanks

Comment: So you want the text 'Column 1' to just be the inner text of .titreck?

Answer (score 2):

use `has()` method... `addClass()` to add class and replace the text of it, using `text()` with the text of descck class

try this

```
$('span.titreck:has(".descck")').addClass('hideme').text($("span.descck").text());
```

Comment: I thought this worked, but it's giving me a problem with more instances, it's adding up contents from each desckk span.

Comment: too late to see your first comment ..anyways glad it helped and you solved it yourself... cheers.. happy coding....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
/*Change the class of the span having a class of titreck that is a parent of the span having a class of descck */
$("span.descck").parent(".titreck").addClass("newClass").removeClass("titreck");
/*Remove the span that has a class of descck*/
$("span.descck").remove();
```

Comment: That affects all `.titreck` elements, which he doesn't want.

Comment: I dont want to remove descck span but its PARENT, titrecl.span. descck span is INSIDE titreck span.

Comment: @donderpiet may be.. thinking that should grab only the immediate parent of the span with that specified class. Did not verify, but I believe that should be correct.

Comment: @Olivera Kovacevic so if you want to remove the parent span then why try to change its class? Trying to follow the exact question. Just tried this solution and it seems to work the way the question was stated, realize I'm probably misunderstanding something.

Comment: Because there are other spans with the same class that i dont want to remove.

Comment: @Olivera Kovacevic do those other parent spans also have child spans with the same class (descck)?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
var de = $('.descck').clone(); //<-----make a copy of this span
$('.descck').remove(); //<-------remove it 
de.insertAfter('.titreck'); //<---insert after its parent
$('.titreck').toggleClass('titreck newClass'); // <---toggle the class to new one
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BDE5K/)